# Как найти значения синуса в Си?

Tags: c

Здравствуйте!

Извините за вери изи, не догоняю

Как в Си получить значения синуса(допустим 30, 60, 90 градусов). Т.е. я подставляю я sin(30), а он мне 0,5.

Запутался с этими радианами.

Спасибо.

Comment: x градусов = x * pi/180 радиан, если не ошибаюсь. Надо просто добавить обертку с этой формулой над обычным радианным синусом.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Упс, наоборот сначала написал, градусы в радианы :)

```
sin(grad*(PI/180));
```

Comment: Недопонял, я как допустим синус 30 вычислить?
PS страно, в vs константы не определяются в либе <math.h>. Они есть, но их не видит компилятор.

Comment: Всё понял. Вот код:

>sin( (30.0*M_PI) / 180));

Comment: `inline double sin_grad( grad ) { return sin(grad*(PI/180)); };`